# MySQL last 7 days being ignored

Tags: mysql

I need to get all the Paid and Provisional Entry from the last 7 days but I keep getting everything returned. I am unsure what I am doing wrong I have read through quite a few posts on here and cant fathom what its. MySQL 5.6 if it makes any diffrence to what I have been doing.

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(ct.entry_date),'%d/%m/%Y') AS booking_date,
cd.field_id_69 AS marriage_date,
cd.field_id_54 AS email_address,
CONCAT(cd.field_id_9, ' ', cd.field_id_10) AS bride_name,
CONCAT(cd.field_id_13, ' ', cd.field_id_14) AS groom_name,
ctco.title AS centre_and_course_date,
(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(col_id_1),'%d/%m/%Y') FROM 
exp_channel_grid_field_50 cg WHERE cg.entry_id = ctco.entry_id ORDER BY 
cg.row_id DESC LIMIT 1) AS course_end_date,
ct.status AS payment_status
FROM exp_channel_titles ct
JOIN exp_channel_data cd ON cd.entry_id = ct.entry_id
JOIN exp_relationships rco ON rco.parent_id = ct.entry_id AND rco.field_id = 41
JOIN exp_channel_titles ctco ON rco.child_id = ctco.entry_id
WHERE ct.channel_id = 2
AND ct.entry_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND ct.status = 'Paid'
AND ct.status = 'Provisional';
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` needs to be followed by 2 dates. You only have one date after it.

Comment: Does the Interval not off set that?

Comment: No, the interval just subtracts an amount of time from `CURDATE()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in your *WHERE* statement

```
  AND ct.entry_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND ct.status = 'Paid' AND ct.status = 'Provisional';
```

The BETWEEN keyword needs to be followed by 2 dates, so *ct.status = 'Paid'* will be converted to *DATE* which return NULL. Hence your *WHERE* statement turns into.

```
  AND ct.entry_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NULL AND ct.status = 'Provisional';
```

The result is that your query will return all data that have status = 'Provisional'.

You could try to modify the *WHERE* statement to

```
  AND ct.entry_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() AND ct.status IN ('Paid', 'Provisional');
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `BETWEEN` is `BETWEEN startdate AND enddate`. You wrote:

```
ct.entry_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND ct.status = 'Paid'
```

So it's using `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` as the starting date, and `ct.status = 'Paid'` as the ending date. I'm surprised it's matching anything.

Change it to:

```
ct.entry_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Or if you don't have any dates in the future, you can simply write:

```
ct.entry_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Both of your suggestions are returning nothing. No Errors, 0 Rows effected

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: `AND ct.status = 'Paid'
AND ct.status = 'Provisional'` is not possible. How can one column be equal to two different things at the same time?

Comment: Maybe you meant `AND ct.status IN ('Paid', 'Provisional')` so it matches either of them?